# Powerline (tmuxline and vim-airline) not showing the right characters [iTerm2, Mac OS X]

Tags: macos, vim, tmux, vim-airline, powerline

so I'm using tmuxline and vim-airline because I don't know how to install powerline for iTerm 2

Anyway they should be looking like tabs but there are characters here not showing. Can anyone help me out?

[image: vim-airline]

Answer (score 8):

My question has been answered. Thanks guys!

For future viewers who might encounter the same problem. All you have to do is the following:

Write this in your terminal (iTerm2 etc...)

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
```

Now find that file (usually ~/)

```
cd powerline/fonts
```

Then type

```
./install.sh
```

After that go to your terminals preferences (usually cmd+,) and go to profiles > *profilename* > Font (Change Font) > Search for "Powerline" and all the installed fonts for powerline should appear > apply.

Use Anti-aliased if you want, and you can separate into two different fonts so that you only need the powerline font for 'Non-ASCII', and your preferred font in 'Font'

Answer (score 6):

Did you install the patched font, as mentioned in [Installation on OS X](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/osx.html)?

> Install downloaded patched font by double-clicking the font file in
>   Finder, then clicking Install this font in the preview window.

Despite the link is to powerline installation manual, vim-airline also [suggests](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) to install that font.

Answer (score 5):

You need special fonts for tmux powerline. You can easily install them from the command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
sudo ./fonts/install.sh
```

Then you change fonts in iTerm2 (both regular and non-ASCII fonts).